# Peculiar behavior of API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

Peculiar behavior of API Gateway:

We have a REST-TO-SOAP API Gateway which acts as a proxy to a service hosted on an instance.

- The curl responses for the authentication from Service instance is as expected.  100/100
- The curl responses for the authentication from API-Gateway is as expected. 100/100 su

We moved the instance behind a ALB (to help us autoscale).

- The curl responses for the authentication from Service (ALB) is also as expected. Ex: 100/100
- The curl responses for the authentication from API-Gateway is 80/100.

We are receiving "Execution failed due to a network error communicating with endpoint". At the ALB of the service we are using default parameters.

**Why is API Gateway behaving differently when there's no change in endpoint for the method?**